# How do I note the accepted range of parameter in YARD?

Tags: ruby, documentation

I would like to document the accepted range of a method with YARD.

I know I can define the type of argument that is accepted, but is there any standard for defining a range? Can I just make it up like in the following example:

```
# @param foo [Range from 0 to 5] the number of foos
```

I ask because there does seem to be some sort of standard for "[declaring types](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Declaring_Types)".

Comment: If the range starts with a certain number and ends with another, I'd use those: `0..5`. If it begins with a certain number and ends anywhere, I'd use `1..n`. If it starts anywhere and ends anywhere, I'd use `n1..n2`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Lacking any definitive answer, I'll adopt that rule of thumb.